# WP_Query orderby random do not repeat infinite scroll - one loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, order, paged

I have found a lot of documentation on solving this issue with multiple loops, I'm finding it hard to see a solution for one custom loop.

Problem: I'm using [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) to load in the next page of posts to the homepage. The posts need to be shown in a random order so I need to store which posts have been shown and then exclude them the second time the query is hit.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in'=> $do_not_duplicate, 
                        'orderby' => 'rand',
                        'category_name' => 'projects', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 20, 
                        'paged' => $paged));
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have built this from http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action - however the approach there is to use `$do_not_duplicate` in the second loop.

Perhaps I need to shuffle this around a bit, store the posts shown in another way, a cookie? Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I don't (completely) get what you're doing right now. Why are you setting `$do_not_duplicate` to the current post's ID - **for each post**? Don't you want to keep track of all the posts already handled? I'd rather store the post IDs in an array (and then eventually implode it to get a comma separated string), or create that string by hand (meaning concatenating).

Comment: Infinite scroll is gong to make a new request to the server for the next set of posts. That is the nature of AJAX. That means that your `$do_not_duplicate` variable will never be populated when it needs to be. You need to find a way to pass that information to the infinite scroll script. I don't see the WordPress specific part of this though. You have that part right, though using `paged` makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution in my functions.php

```
 /*------ order ------*/
session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION["sem"];

        if (empty($seed)) {
          $seed = rand();
          $_SESSION["sem"] = $seed;
        }

        $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
        return $orderby_statement;  

}
```

And additionaly, in the page where you show the posts, in the top of the file, i reset the session variable to can start ordering again random in each reload at this way:

```
$semilla = rand();

$_SESSION["sem"] = $semilla;
```

Works for me very well.